# Why raise_for_status() did not catch the error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, spotify, api-design

Trying to check for none 200 Response in the current_track() function. What could be a problem? It throwing JSONDecodeError error. But if I understood raise_for_ status correctly it should have prevented the function from trying to load a JSON from a faulty web-page? If I run the script without this check and with uncommenting lines check_playback() it successfully catches JSONDecodeError.

The script is fetching data from Spotify and putting it to the status on vk.com.

```
import config
import webbrowser
import requests
import furl
import secrets
import string
import time
import os
import simplejson as json


URL_CODE_BASE_VK = 'https://oauth.vk.com/authorize'
URL_CODE_BASE_SP = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize'
URL_TOKEN_VK = 'https://oauth.vk.com/access_token'
URL_TOKEN_SP = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'
URL_TRACK = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing'
URL_STATUS = 'https://api.vk.com/method/status.set'
EXP_IN_TOKEN_SP = 3400
EXP_IN_TOKEN_VK = 86400
FILE_TOKEN_VK = 'vk_token.json'
FILE_TOKEN_SP = 'sp_token.json'


def get_auth_code_vk():
    url_code_params = {
                        'client_id': config.CLIENT_ID_VK,
                        'response_type': 'code',
                        'redirect_uri': 'https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html',
                        'v': 5.92,
                        'scope': 'status',
                        'state': gen_state(),
                        'display': 'page'
    }

    code = url_open(URL_CODE_BASE_VK, url_code_params)
    return parse_code(code)


def get_auth_code_sp():
    url_code_params = {
                        'client_id': config.CLIENT_ID_SP,
                        'response_type': 'code',
                        'redirect_uri': 'https://www.spotify.com/',
                        'scope': 'user-read-currently-playing',
                        'state': gen_state()
    }

    code = url_open(URL_CODE_BASE_SP, url_code_params)
    return parse_code(code)


def gen_state():
    symbols = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
    return ''.join(secrets.choice(symbols) for _ in range(12))


def url_open(url_base, url_params):
    url_code_full = furl.furl(url_base).add(url_params).url
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url_code_full)
    input_url = input('Enter the whole URL, that you have been redirected on: ')

    return input_url


def parse_code(url):
    return (url.split("code=")[1]).split("&state=")[0]


def get_token_vk():
    data = {
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'code': get_auth_code_vk(),
            'redirect_uri': 'https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html',
            'client_id': 6782333,
            'client_secret': config.CLIENT_SECRET_VK
    }

    response = requests.post(url=URL_TOKEN_VK, data=data).json()
    write_file(FILE_TOKEN_VK, response)


def get_token_sp():
    data = {
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'code': get_auth_code_sp(),
            'redirect_uri': 'https://www.spotify.com/',
            'client_id': config.CLIENT_ID_SP,
            'client_secret': config.CLIENT_SECRET_SP
    }

    response = requests.post(url=URL_TOKEN_SP, data=data).json()
    write_file(FILE_TOKEN_SP, response)


def write_file(tkn_file, response):
    dict = {}
    dict['token'] = response["access_token"]
    dict['time'] = time.time()

    with open(tkn_file, 'w') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(dict))


def load_file(tkn_file):
    with open(tkn_file) as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    return data


def set_status():
    params = {
              'v': 5.92,
              'access_token': load_file(FILE_TOKEN_VK)['token'],
              'text': current_track()
    }

    set_status = requests.get(url=URL_STATUS, params=params)


def track_data():
    tkn_file =  load_file(FILE_TOKEN_SP)['token']
    headers = {
               'Accept': 'application/json',
               'Authorization': f'Bearer {tkn_file}'
    }

    return requests.get(url=URL_TRACK, headers=headers)


def current_track():
    response = track_data()
    print(response)

    try:
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        return "Error: " + str(e)

    # data = track_data().json()
    data = response.json()
    artist = data['item']['artists'][0]['name']
    track = data['item']['name']

    return(f'{artist} - {track}')


def check_playback():
    set_status()
    print(current_track())
    # try:
    #     set_status()
    #     print(current_track())
    # except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
    #     print('Not playing')


def token_missing(file):
    return not os.path.isfile(file)


def token_expired(file, exp_in):
    return time.time() - load_file(file)['time'] > exp_in


def token_not_valid(file, exp_in):
    return token_missing(file) or token_expired(file, exp_in)


def run_script():
    if token_not_valid(FILE_TOKEN_VK, EXP_IN_TOKEN_VK):
        get_token_vk()

    if token_not_valid(FILE_TOKEN_SP, EXP_IN_TOKEN_SP):
        get_token_sp()

    check_playback()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_script()
```

[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpjqZ.png)

Comment: Note that a page can return a 200 status but contain "broken" JSON. You should really check the contents of the response as raw text before trying to parse it.

Comment: Please try to provide a minimal example of what you're asking about. If it crashes before the VK bit runs then remove it. If you rely on an external API that requires authentication then you can replace that with a call to [httpbin](https://httpbin.org/#/), and so on.

Comment: Sorry for not providing all the info, @Bakuriu, @Teo Klestrup Röijezon I'm actually printing the response in the `current_track` function, it says that there is 204 status. So there is no JSON, but it is not actually an error. Just a "no data" response. For some reason, I was under the wrong  impression that `raise_for_status` raises an Exception every time there is not a 200 response.

Comment: So the question is, do I really need to use `raise_for_status` anywhere in this script?

Comment: @Flynn84 It depends. HTTP has dozens of status codes. All 2XX status code signify success. And typically 3XX status code are success too, though they tell you to redirect. Only 4XX and 5XX status codes are errors. `raise_for_status` only considers 4XX and 5XX as errors. `204 NO CONTENT` is a fine response, so you should handle it correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`raise_for_status()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status) will only raise an exception if the *server* reported an error to you (and even then, only if it actually followed the HTTP spec and returned a HTTP error code).

There is no way for the library to know that the response is incorrect. Even if it was correctly formatted JSON, it can't know what schema you expect it to follow (what fields should be present, and what types those fields should have). Even if it knew the schema and had verified it, there is no way for it to know that the data is actually correct and not made up on the spot.